# Using RewriteEngine / mod_rewrite for login system?

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite, web, authentication, url-rewriting

Is it possible to build a login system using mod_rewrite? To be more specific on the problem: I have some static webpages that are build by a website generator and cannot modify by myself. But these webpages and their original URLs shall not be able to be accesed by the public. There is also a WordPress website using a login-system running on the same domain.

So, my idea to protect the static webpages to the public was to use a mod_rewrite rule, based on the WP session cookie. Is that even possible? Or is there even a cleaner and simpler solution for that? EDIT: The idea is also to have the same user database as the wordpress blog.

Cheers,
Valentin

Comment: You can set up basic auth in Apache to password protect static html pages.

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit unspesific when I asked that question. Thats the way it is running now. But the overall Idea is, to have the same users as the WordPress blog.

Comment: You might have to convert the static pages to wordpress pages to take advantage of the wordpress authentication system. But there's a bunch a wordpress plugins out there for static pages. There might be one that could be used to solve this, though the typical use for static sites is to be served with no login required.

Comment: Yeah, I know.  As I wrote these webpages automatically build by a static engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. All you can do in mod_rewrite is check whether a WordPress session cookie exists, but you cannot check whether it's valid or has been set by WordPress (and not just made up by the User who is trying to gain access).

Håken Lid is right, [HTTP auth (for apache 2.4)](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/auth.html) ([2.2 docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html)) is the right way to go if you don't want to add a PHP script that does the authentication against the WP database and then prints the content if the user is authenticated.

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit unspesific when I asked that question. HTTP auth is the way it is running now. But the overall Idea is, to have the same users as the WordPress blog.

But the idea of writing a PHP script to authenticate the users does seem to be a good idea.

Comment: You'll have to write a script, make it handle all requests to that directory with mod_rewrite and handle authentication against the WP database in that script I'm afraid.

Comment: Yeah, i think, I'm gonna do that. Thank you!